# Nvidia DLSS cannot be loaded due to outdated driver

Tags: no-mans-sky, graphics-card

I am aware of how to fix this, but a lot of times the outdated drivers complaints are meaningless.  The game runs fine when i press ok.  Am I missing out on anything by the DLSS not being loaded?  Will my graphics look nicer or run better if i update my driver?  (Please don't answer with:  "It's generally better to keep your drivers up to date"  I'm aware of this and updated not that long ago.  My question is what will updating improve)  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an NVIDIA RTX-series graphics card? If not, then DLSS is not supported. Regardless, I don't think this is a great question, as "look nicer" or "run better" can be pretty subjective things. DLSS as a concept is meant to increase graphics performance, so, you've essentially answered your own question already, which is, "yeah, it should look and run better."

Comment: My point was that a lot of times the outdated driver warning is completely meaningless.  They were specifically stating that something was not loading, so it made me wonder if a large feature of my graphics card wasn't being used or something.  (I didn't know what dlss is)  My graphics card is a GTX 750 ti, so I assume it's incompatible with dlss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### About DLSS

DLSS stands for "Deep Learning Super Sampling", and is a technique developed by Nvidia to increase the rendered frame's resolution using a Deep Learning AI model. The technology can only be used with Nvidia's RTX-series cards, as it uses the Tensor Cores only found on RTX cards.

While it was made to increase an existing image's resolution (also known as "upsampling"), DLSS is commonly used to improve graphics performance. This is done by rendering the game at a lower resolution, then using DLSS to upsample it to the desired resolution. For example, if you want to play at 4K, the game might render at 1080p instead, and use DLSS to upsample the frame to the 4K target resolution.

Thus the main (and so far only) benefit of DLSS (assuming you have the RTX GPU to use it) is to improve performance.

Further reading: https://developer.nvidia.com/dlss

#### About driver updates

One thing to note about driver updates (particularly for Nvidia GPUs), is that they usually contain so-called "profiles" for games.

These profiles basically tell your GPU how to handle draw calls made by that specific game, in order to optimize performance. This works because of how older graphics APIs (like DirectX 11 and older, or OpenGL) worked.

These APIs were designed to be (relatively) easy to use. This meant that the GPU usually had to make assumptions about the developer's intent, and what the game is trying to achieve. Sometimes it made the wrong assumption, and games didn't perform as well as they could. Game profiles were therefore made to correct the assumptions made by the GPU, so games could perform better.

This was usually only done for newly released games, and usually only for more recent GPUs. According to Nvidia ([https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34/~/how-often-to-update-graphics-card-display-drivers](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34/%7E/how-often-to-update-graphics-card-display-drivers)):

> If your NVIDIA based graphics card is a newer model, it is recommended that you update your graphic card drivers regularly to get the best performance and experience from your PC. **If your NVIDIA based graphics card is an older model**, then we suggest you update your drivers only if you are experiencing problems while running newer software on your PC.

So you're not wrong about not needing to update your drivers, seeing as the GTX 750 Ti is already 7 years old, which is very old by PC hardware standards.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how (or if) these profiles help performance in games using newer APIs (like DirectX 12, Vulkan, or Metal), if they are used at all.

Comment: The part about GPU drivers, game profiles, and performance came from a reddit post by someone claiming to have worked at Nvidia's as a driver developer. I'm trying to find that specific post, but reddit doesn't seem to be working for me right now. I'll update my answer when I can.

Comment: thanks, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that DLSS is a deep learning neural network on RTX cards that increases framerates and improves the images in your game. Games have to be patched to utilise DLSS so not every game is compatible even if your RTX card is. Using a 750 you don't have to worry about a lack of DLSS, it will make no difference to your gaming purely based on the age of your graphics card. Updating will improve nothing at all for you as far as DLSS goes. This nag screen also pops up for people using RTX cards, myself included, because I let Nvidia G-Sync install the driver instead of updating through Windows myself. It's new tech still so has teething problems and I've been hovering on the Nvidia forums waiting to see how it goes..